# Pyspark Dataframe Joins Incorrectly when there are multiple nested fields

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data-frame which has schema like this:

```
root
 |-- docId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Country: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- s1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- Gender: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- s1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- s2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- s3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- s4: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- s5: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- YOB: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- s1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- s2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- s3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- s4: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

I have a new data frame which has schema like this:

```
root
 |-- docId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Country: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- s6: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- Gender: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- s6: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- YOB: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- s6: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

I want to join these data-frames and have the structure like:

```
root
 |-- docId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Country: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- s1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- s6: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- Gender: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- s1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- s2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- s3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- s4: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- s5: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- s6: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- YOB: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- s1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- s2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- s3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- s4: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true) 
 |    |-- s5: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

But in-turn I am getting data frame after join like this:
root

```
 |-- docId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Country: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- s1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- Country: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- s6: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- Gender: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- s1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- s2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- s3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- s4: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- s5: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- Gender: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- s6: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- YOB: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- s1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- s2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- s3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- s4: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |-- YOB: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- s6: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

What should be done?
I have done and outer join on the field docId and the above data frame is the one that I get.

Comment: Have you tried exploding the dataframes and then join?

Comment: Exploding will be equivalent to flattening the structure and then joining which would work definitely but I am looking for some better approach if at all it exist.

Answer (score 0):

The Dataframe is not 'joined incorrectly', as a `JOIN` operation is not supposed to sort Structs out. You get seemingly duplicate columns because the `JOIN` is taking the columns from both dataframes when combining. You have to do the combination explicitly:

Initialization

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import types as T
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession(sc)
```

First, the data (I added only some columns for reference, extending it to your full example is trivial):

```
Country_schema1 = T.StructField("Country", T.StructType([T.StructField("s1", T.StringType(), nullable=True)]), nullable=True)
Gender_schema1 = T.StructField("Gender", T.StructType([T.StructField("s1", T.StringType(), nullable=True),
                                                      T.StructField("s2", T.StringType(), nullable=True)]))
schema1 = T.StructType([T.StructField("docId", T.StringType(), nullable=True),
                       Country_schema1,
                       Gender_schema1
                       ])
data1 = [("1",["1"], ["M", "X"])]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, schema=schema1)
df1.toJSON().collect()
```

Output:

```
['{"docId":"1","Country":{"s1":"1"},"Gender":{"s1":"M","s2":"X"}}']
```

Second dataframe:

```
Country_schema2 = T.StructField("Country", T.StructType([T.StructField("s6", T.StringType(), nullable=True)]), nullable=True)
Gender_schema2 = T.StructField("Gender", T.StructType([T.StructField("s6", T.StringType(), nullable=True),
                                                      T.StructField("s7", T.StringType(), nullable=True)]))
schema2 = T.StructType([T.StructField("docId", T.StringType(), nullable=True),
                       Country_schema2,
                       Gender_schema2
                       ])
data2 = [("1",["2"], ["F", "Z"])]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, schema=schema2)
df2.toJSON().collect()
```

Output:

```
['{"docId":"1","Country":{"s6":"2"},"Gender":{"s6":"F","s7":"Z"}}']
```

Now the logic. I think this is easier if done using SQL. Create the tables first:

```
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")
```

This is the query to execute. It basically indicates which fields are to be `SELECT`ed (instead of all of them) and wraps the ones from the `StructField`s in a new structure which combines them:

```
result = spark.sql("SELECT df1.docID, "
                   "STRUCT(df1.Country.s1 AS s1, df2.Country.s6 AS s6) AS Country, "
                   "STRUCT(df1.Gender.s2 AS s2, df2.Gender.s6 AS s6, df2.Gender.s7 AS s7) AS Gender "
                   "FROM df1 JOIN df2 ON df1.docID=df2.docID")
result.show()
```

Output:

```
+-----+-------+---------+
|docID|Country|   Gender|
+-----+-------+---------+
|    1| [1, 2]|[X, F, Z]|
+-----+-------+---------+
```

It is better viewed in JSON:

```
result.toJSON().collect()

['{"docID":"1","Country":{"s1":"1","s6":"2"},"Gender":{"s2":"X","s6":"F","s7":"Z"}}']
```